# Searching documents and sub documents from two databases in IBM Notes

Tags: performance, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In IBM Notes I have two databases

Orders.nsf and OrdersArchive.nsf

In the Orders.nsf database I have Orderdocuments and Orderline documents
One Order could have X Orderlines.

For example Order 1 has two orderlines:

1. Cartire
2. Lamp

So in total there are one Order document and two Orderline documents.

The Orders.nsf database contains all orders from 2014 until now.
All older orders + orderlines are in the OrdersArchive.nsf database.

Now there is a view in both database in which people can search for ordelines. So for example John searches for Cartire and sees that there are previous orderlines with cartire..
The problem is that John needs to do the search in the Orders.nsf database and the OrdersArchive.nsf database. Because the order with cartire orderline could be from 2016 but could also be from 2010.

For this I have a new server on which I have a orders.nsf database in which I copied all orders and orderlines from both two database. So that John could search in that database to see if any orderlines or orders already exist..

Problem now is that you have 2 documents. Is there a simpler way to solve this.
Like create 1 view on Server 1 which gets all orders an orderlines from the Orders.nsf and the OrdersArchive.nsf database? Or will this reduce performance?

Comment: How many documents are in each database? And when users search in OrdersArchive, is performance okay?

Comment: In orders.nsf  aprox 250k  ordersArchive.nsf aprox 750k

Comment: Is search performance okay in ordersArchive.nsf?

Comment: IF indexed then yes its ok

Comment: So then my question is: why not have orders.nsf contain all orders from 2014 until now, but ordersArchive contain all orders plus copies of all orders in orders.nsf? Yes, you would have to some write code to keep both copies in synch while orders in orders.nsf are still being processed (I assume they are updated from time of creation until time the order is final.)  But then the advantage is you would have only one place to search, while still maintaining higher performance in orders.nsf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix two views from different databases into one view in Notes client by default. You can create a search result form that list all entries from both views in an rich text field. But this takes some effort...

There is an easier way in your case:

- create a form with SaveOptions="0" that contains both views as embedded views
- categorize both views by orderline product
- show only current orderline product in both embedded views
- add a button "show all" to orderline that creates a document based on that form for current orderline product

This way, the user sees all entries for a orderline product at once right from an orderline product without the need to switch to and search in two views.

Comment: where to put SaveOptions="0" ??

Comment: It is a trick to not be able and not to be asked to save a document. Create a field "SaveOptions" on form and assign value "0".

Comment: Wow nice thanks! Now I created a form in the orders.nsf database and created an embedded view with orderlines from order.nsf database. But I also try to create an embedded view and try to select ordersArchive.nsf but it is not listed, I already opened it in designer and it is on the same server. Any Idea why this happens??

Comment: If the ordersArchive.nsf is bookmarked on Notes Client then it should be available in selection. But, databases are listed by database title and not by file name.

Comment: If I get results in the embededd view is it also possible to then get for example the price from the result documents?

Comment: You can add it as a column to view. User can also open the orderline document with a click and look for all fields there.

Comment: If I am in the order document which has an embedded view of the orderlines. Is it also possible to put there a button "show existing orderlines" which looks at the orderline description of every line in the embedded view and then checks if it exists?

Comment: Rather not. I'd put the button "show existing orderlines" into the orderline itself.

Comment: An orderline has an item ID and a Description column. Would it also be possible that when user clicks this button that he can search on for example cartire or an item id?

Comment: By default I'd use the item id of current orderline as "show single category" value in embedded view (and categorize views by item id). You might ask for another product or item id before you open the form with the embedded views but this might be irritating for user.

Comment: It works it only takes long to open the embedded view for items from the orderarchive database because it contains 3x times more documents as the order database

Answer (score 3):

You should try `Domain Search`. More information:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_WHAT_IS_DOMAIN_SEARCH_OVER.html

But if you familiar with coding you can try to add some functionality with using *LotusScript* also. The code should be use something like this:

```
   Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
   Set collection = db.AllDocuments
   Call collection.FTSearch("pirelli", 10)
```

more information here:
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/12f371c99182bae78525642e0075cdc8?OpenDocument

Comment: Just a reminder: Domain Search doesn't take field names into account.